# The application will disappear from the list of applications with the received access

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth, google-developers-console

Hello everyone and firstly Im sorry for my lame English.

From time to time, we have problems with updating the token, or rather, we simply can not use the refresh_token
This is what it looks like:

1. We allow the app access manually and get the first access_token and refresh_token. At this stage, everything is OK, the application is in the list that was granted access (check through this page: https://myaccount.google.com/permissions ):

[image: Screenshot (apps with the received access)]

2. AcessToken successfully used and updated for some time (usually several weeks), but then the app from the list of apps that got access disappears (https://myaccount.google.com/permissions)

And disappears as if someone manually denies him access.

And, of course, the last access_token stops working, and with it the refresh_token.
After that, we again need to manually confirm the app's access for the first time. Because refresh_token, certainly, is not valid after the app disappears from the list.

Please, anybody, tell me what this might be related to. And for what reason can an app disappear from the list, if no one manually restricts access to app?

Maybe there are some reasons: improper use of tokens and so on-the reasons why the application may disappear. Or private account settings that we don't know about? We will be glad to receive any suggestions, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is still in testing or has not been though the verification process then refresh tokens will expire between one to two weeks.  This may also cause the application to be removed from the users permission, however I cant say I have actually checked but it makes sense.  From googles end the easiest way to ensure a refresh token will expire would be to revoke the users permission.

[image]

Set the app to production and apply for verification.  Should fix the issue.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, we apologize for not reading the documentation well. I can't vote for the answer due to lack of reputation. Thank you again.

Comment: I have a video on the subject.  All the links in the description may interest you https://youtu.be/lzIuNmNX9N8

Comment: This is interesting, we will definitely get acquainted, thank you, just Google documentation very big, and our Russian searching (yandex) it seems to lower the rating of some issues according to their documentation, because I really couldn't find it, but maybe I'm wrong, and I just looked badly. Thank you again and good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition about what @DaImTo has posted; in the following [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration) you could find information about the list of different reasons regarding why the token could be failing like:

> - The user has revoked your app's access.
> - The refresh token has not been used for six months.
> - The user changed passwords and the refresh token contains Gmail    scopes.
> - The user account has exceeded a maximum number of granted (live)    refresh tokens.
> - The user belongs to a Google Cloud Platform organization that has    session control policies in effect.

It also states that publishes with the "Testing" status has a refresh token expiring for 7 days.

> A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen
> configured for an external user type and a publishing status of
> "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

Bear in mind that there is also a limit of 50 refresh tokens in case you reach this limit. Check the referred documentation for further information.

Comment: Thank you, I apologize for my blindness, but I couldn't find it by searching. I will study the documentation, now we are submitting applications for testing applications, thank you again very much and good luck to you.