# Verification Google OAuth2 concert scren with the apps for personal use only

Tags: google-oauth, google-developers-console

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68188814/the-application-will-disappear-from-the-list-of-applications-with-the-received-a) and user's @DalmTo and @Sergio NH they gave me an exhaustive answer for which I thank them very much.

Moving forward to question, we started publishing the application, and its verification was not required, since no scope was added (here it is a little unclear why the requests worked in an application with a test mode in which these scope were not added (google drive, google sheet and google ads)).

However, this time the application in the "In Production" mode began to give us an "Unverified app screen" (see [Unverified app screen](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865)). We decided that we still need to add scope to the list, and, of course, that the scope list (their list is described above) requires verification by Google.

We started filling in the necessary fields, while studying the Google documentation at the same time, and came across the following information (see block [Verification process -> What are the requirements for verification?](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#verification-process&zippy=%2Cwhat-are-the-requirements-for-verification)):

> Apps not applicable for verification
> Apps for internal use only
> (single domain use) **Apps for personal use only** Apps that are Gmail
> SMTP plugins for WordPress Apps that are in development or
> staging/testing

**Apps for personal use only**

And this is just our case: we have already received permission from Google Ads and are just generating simple reports that we want to integrate with Google Sheet. I.e., this is an elementary script that works within this account (however, we still need to request the first concert screen, even for this developer account) and cannot be distributed to any other accounts.

But when adding our scope, Google requires us to pass verification, forcing us to fill in the required fields, in the form of domains and their verification via the Search Console (we have already done this and this stage does not cause difficulties) and links to Youtube videos - where we must show how scope is used.

**And just this stage is not clear.** We do not allow other people's accounts to connect to this application, and the software does not have any interface, it is just a script that receives data from Google Ads and saves it to Google Sheet (creating a file via Google Drive). We have described all this in the scope usage description field. But the link to the Youtube video is **require field**, and we sincerely do not understand **why (considering our case)** we should record something, and most importantly, **what exactly we should record** in this case. If the documentation itself says that in our case we do not even need a verification.

Maybe we did not understand something and now we are doing it wrong? We will be glad to receive any tips from experts working with Google Cloud Console and apologize in advance for broken English.

We also apologize in advance to the StackOverflow community that we have to publish such elementary (which we are absolutely sure of from our side) questions here. We come here from Google Cloud Console - > Support - > Community support, and we must first try to publish posts in the Google Groups specified there, but they simply do not answer us, apparently considering our questions too elementary and not worthy of attention (however, these same questions in Google Groups are moderated) (for example, [the previous question](https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-dev/c/vyDzoaNlrVM/m/Z_nDYPbOBAAJ)). And we are no longer able to contact any other support. Once again, we apologize for having to ask about this here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that if your app is a single use app then you do not need to be verified.

However if you don't get your app verified then there will be some restrictions.

1. you will see the unverified app screen
2. your refresh tokens will probably only be good for two weeks.
3. In the case of the YouTube api uploaded videos will be suck private.

If you can live with those points then you don't need to verify your app and you can continue as is.

If on the other hand you don't want to see the unverified app screen and you want a refresh token that will last longer then two weeks. You will need to verify your app.  Yes, Even if your app is a console application running as a job some where you still show the consent screen.  This is the YouTube video you will need to show Google.  Show the consent screen popping up show the URL bar and then show your script running.  You also need to set up the homepage and privacy policy screens.  Yes i 100% agree with you that this is silly.

When you go though the process. Explain to google that this is a single use script running as a job some where.

Unfortunately when Google changed it so that Refresh tokens expire for unverified apps they pretty much tied the hands of all developers who are running such single user scripts.  We now have to get our apps verified if we don't want to have to request a new refresh token every two weeks.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. The support responded to us, but did not tell us that the lifetime of the new tokens will be no more than two weeks. They said that you can stay in the unverified mode. Now we will continue to deal with them, could you point to the link to the documentation, which says about two weeks of the token's life? It is just this condition that forces us to eventually fulfill all their requirements. Since we need to launch the application, configure logs and notifications for a fire event and "forget" about it, but do not issue access manually every two weeks:)

Comment: Feel free to try.  I have tested it and found that the users access is revoked which causes the refresh token to expire.  I have also answered a number of questions on SO related to it and others have tried over the last few months.   I suspect this is a stealth change and a lot of the Google Teams have not been informed.    Please let me know if it does not fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you, we will continue to use the application and keep in touch with support until we are completely sure that our application will no longer require our attention, we will write a comment to your answer for any changes.

Comment: I sent an email to someone at about getting some documentation on this.   Keep me updated then we can give google some additional feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If your program needs to access the requested scopes of the Google account privacy, even though the user is yourself, you also need to provide a youtube video to demonstrate how you use this program. The auditor cannot guarantee whether you will make this program public.

Comment: ok, but judging by [**this documentation**](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#verification-process&zippy=%2Cwhat-are-the-requirements-for-verification) (see block **App demonstration video**) it turns out that they want to see how we use scope. And this is a pure script, i.e. just code. Maybe I don't understand something, but do they offer me to show them the code? After all, this is not an application in the full sense of the word, it lacks an interface, otherwise, what else should I record on video with them? (sorry my English)