# Google API GMail oauth2 can't refresh a RefreshToken after a week

Tags: powershell, google-oauth, gmail-api

I've a system that sends an email every day using GMail API.

- I get the **RefreshToken** once then save it to a file.
- before send daily mail the RefreshToken is refreshed to get the *SingleUse* **AccessToken**

These are my functions:

```
function GoogleAPI-GetRefreshToken($clientID, $clientSecret, $redirect_url = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob")   
{   
    # https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app

    Set-Clipboard ("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send&include_granted_scopes=true&response_type=code&redirect_uri={0}&client_id={1}" -f $redirect_url, $clientID)
    Write-Host "The authorization URL has been copied into the clipboard. Paste it in the browser and follows the instruction."
    $clientAuthCode = Read-Host "AuthorizationCode"

    $tokenParams = @{
          client_id=$clientID;
          client_secret=$clientSecret;
          code=$clientAuthCode;
          grant_type='authorization_code';
          redirect_uri=$redirect_url
        }

    $token = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" -Method POST -Body $tokenParams | ConvertFrom-Json

    # Use refresh token to get new access token
    # The access token is used to access the api by sending the access_token parm with every request. 
    # Access tokens are only valid for an hour, after that you will need to request a new one using your refresh_token
    
    return $token.refresh_token  
}

function GoogleAPI-GetAccessToken($clientID, $clientSecret, $refreshToken)
{
    $RefreshTokenParams = @{
      client_id=$clientID;
      client_secret=$clientSecret;
      refresh_token=$refreshToken;
      grant_type='refresh_token';
    }

    $refreshedToken = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token" -Method POST -Body $refreshTokenParams | ConvertFrom-Json)
    
    return $refreshedToken.access_token
}
```

Main code, first I get the **RefreshToken** from the API (first time) or from the previous saved one (from file):

```
if (! (Test-Path $clientFile))
{
    $refreshToken = GoogleAPI-GetRefreshToken $clientID $clientSecret
    $refreshToken | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Path $clientFile
}
else
{
    $refreshToken = Get-Content $clientFile | ConvertFrom-Json
}
```

Next I get a new **AccessToken**:

```
$accessToken = GoogleAPI-GetAccessToken $clientID $clientSecret $refreshToken
```

Finally I use the AccessToken to **send** the daily mail:

```
Mail-Send -accessToken $accessToken -from me@gmail.com -to you@gmail.com -subject "daily mail" -body "hello"
```

> **THE PROBLEM: 
>
> This only works for a week than I get an error from GoogleAPI-GetAccessToken** 
> *Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.*

I know there's a limit of 50 on client/user and user refresh operation ([doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)) but I don't know how to overcome that problem and let the system send daily mail for ever without having to ask user to do the authentication again.

Any idea ? 
Thank you

Comment: There is no limit to the number of times you can use your refresh token.   Make sure that if you do authorize the user again that you save the new refresh token you should always be running on the most recent refresh token.    Note 400 error is not an authorization error.  There is an error with your request itself.

Comment: The code is not PHP, rather it is PowerShell.

Comment: Thank you @DalmTo I'm sure the authorize token is unique and I save it.
The limit exists according to **google api documentation** https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2 is 50

Comment: I think your Google Cloud project has a "Testing" publishing status. You should set the status to "Production". See for a good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68190012/1294832